python polarsで時間を設定してStringで取り出す方法
Pythonのpolarsライブラリーを使って時間の設定を行いたいです。
設定した時間を使って、DataFrame内のDate.Timeから特定の時間を取り出すことはできますが、同じ方法で単純に時間だけをStringに変換することができず困っています。
具体的には以下のような問題が発生しています。
import polars as pl
from datetime import timedelta

ip = pl.datetime(2024, 11, 8, 13, 29)
ep = ip + timedelta(minutes=duration1) - timedelta(seconds=1)
print (ip) #-->2024-11-08 13:29:00.alias("datetime")
print (ep) #-->[([(2024-11-08 13:29:00.alias("datetime")) + (2m)]) - (1s)]

このような条件下で、ip, epの時間だけを取り出すことは可能でしょうか？
ご教授頂けたら、幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。


python polarsで時間を設定してStringで取り出す方法

問題は解決してそうですが, タイトルの質問については記されてなく
タイトルで検索して辿り着いた場合の回答をとりあえず記します
polars.datetime によると, Expr を返すことになっていて, そのままでは無理
以下のように(Expr利用する場面で使用)すれば内容が取り出せます
(timedeltaなど指定がない場合)
>>> import polars as pl
>>> print(pl.DataFrame()
...         .select(pl.datetime(2024, 11, 8, 13, 29)))
shape: (1, 1)
┌─────────────────────┐
│ datetime            │
│ ---                 │
│ datetime[μs]        │
╞═════════════════════╡
│ 2024-11-08 13:29:00 │
└─────────────────────┘
>>>


ありがとうございます。また、中途半端に答えを返して申し訳なかったです。Oriri様の補足に感謝します。

plとdatetime以下にあるdatetimeを取り間違えておりました。
問題は以下のように解決できました。
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
ip = datetime(2024, 11, 8, 13, 29) # not pl.datetime
ep = ip + timedelta(minutes=2) - timedelta(seconds=1)
print (ip)
print (ep)
この設定した時間はDataframe内のDate.Timeにも適用できることを確認しました。
